In Android, how should I know where this broadcast is coming from?
In the source code of AOSP：
packages/services/Telephony/src/com/android/phone/PhoneGlobals.java
    /**
     * Receiver for misc intent broadcasts the Phone app cares about.
     */
    private class PhoneAppBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED)) {
                boolean airplaneMode = intent.getBooleanExtra("state", false);
                handleAirplaneModeChange(airplaneMode);

This is a broadcast receiver, but I don’t know where the broadcast is sent. There are too many places where broadcasts are sent.
Ways I can think of:
Add logs to all places where broadcasts are sent. I have to add at least dozens of logs, and then determine whether the specific broadcast is sent in a certain piece of code.

You can use the Intent extras as identifiers to figure out where the intent is coming from.
At each of the places where the broadcast code is called you can:
intentToBroadcast.putExtra("origin", "your_unique_identifier");

At the broadcast receiver you can:
String origin = intent.getStringExtra("origin");
//if-else ladder, switch case etc.

I'd use constant integer primitives defined in a Constants class to denote each class that calls the broadcast.
